# Turning on raster painting toolbar of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, editing, erase, arcscan

My aim is to delete raster cells using the [erase tool in the raster painting toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/extensions/arcscan/using-the-raster-painting-erase-tools.htm). However, the raster painting tool bar won't turn on in ArcMap (it is greyed out), as the screenshot below.

[image]

How do I turn the toolbar on and use the erase tool to erase raster cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That toolbar is part of ArcScan, and so it may be that you have not enabled that extension.

From [Getting Started with ArcScan](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm#GUID-D2E9A8EC-CC90-4796-842D-245B6C3747DF):

> As with other ArcGIS extensions, you must enable the ArcScan extension
>   in ArcMap before you can use it.

If this does not activate the buttons on that toolbar make sure that your map contains at least one raster dataset and be aware that:

> Since ArcScan is designed to work with editing, you must start an edit
>   session to activate the toolbar.

and that:

> ArcScan can vectorize any raster format supported by ArcGIS so long as
>   it is represented as a bi-level image.

It may be that you are trying to use it on an image that is not bi-level.